# javascript simple calculator not returning value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using a simple calculator form and i am trying to use javascript to calculate the total. I have referenced the source and ID's correct, however i will upload.

When clicking the calculate button the page refreshes the values back to normal.

see below for HTML and JS

```js
function calculate() {

  'use strict';

  var total;

  var quantity = document.getElementsById('quantity').value;
  var unitPrice = document.getElementById('price').value;
  var theVat = document.getElementById('vat').value;
  var theDiscount = document.getElementById('discount').value;

  total = quantity * unitPrice;
  total = total + (total * theVat / 100) - (total * theDiscount / 100);
  total = total.toFixed(2);

  document.getElementById('total').value = "£" + total;

  return false;
}


function initCal() {

  'use strict';

  document.getElementById('theCalculatorForm').onsubmit = calculate;

}

window.onload = initCal;
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Innovative Multimedia - Simple Calculator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row columns text-center">
      <h2>Innovative Multimedia - Introduction to JavaScript</h2>
      <p> In this application the user will enter the required details and the application will calculate the total cost.</p>

    </div>
    <div class="row">

      <h3> Simple Calculator</h3>
      <form action="" method="post" id="theCalculatorForm">
        <fieldset>
          <p>Use this form to calculate the order total.</p>
          <div><label for="quantity">Quantity</label><input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="1" min="1" required></div>
          <div><label for="price">Price Per Unit</label><input type="number" name="price" id="price" value="1.00" required></div>
          <div><label for="vat">VAT (%)</label><input type="number" name="vat" id="vat" value="17" required disabled></div>
          <div><label for="discount">Discount (%)</label><input type="number" name="discount" id="discount" value="10" required disabled></div>
          <div><label for="total">Total</label><input type="text" name="total" id="total" value="0" required disabled></div>
          <div><input type="submit" value="Calculate" id="submitCal"></div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>


  </div>

  <script src="js/calculator.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/what-input.js"></script>
  <script src="js/foundation.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

If you need anything please ask.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? Do you see any errors?

Comment: What do you mean by 'the page refreshes? Reloads?

Comment: `getElementsById` should be singular, `getElementById`

Comment: You should have a look at [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) to help debugging. It seems here your problem will be that you're not preventing the form from submitting.

Comment: Thanks! @j08691 stupid mistake

Comment: Try using [`Event.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) at the top of the calculate function instead of `return false` at the end, that way if there's an error in the code after that point, the form still won't actually submit. That should help you in future for debugging too.

Comment: Don't you want  ** ..... onsubmit = calculate();**  ?  You're missing the **()**

Answer (score 0):

`<form>` we use it to send data by two methods (post/get) so when you click
in Button calculate all values sends and page refreshed 
use div for exemple to not refresh the web page

replace the form tag with div 
like this

```
    <div id="theCalculatorForm">

          </div>
<!---- Your code after will be like this ------>
<div  id="theCalculatorForm">
        <fieldset>
          <p>Use this form to calculate the order total.</p>
          <div><label for="quantity">Quantity</label><input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="1" min="1" required></div>
          <div><label for="price">Price Per Unit</label><input type="number" name="price" id="price" value="1.00" required></div>
          <div><label for="vat">VAT (%)</label><input type="number" name="vat" id="vat" value="17" required disabled></div>
          <div><label for="discount">Discount (%)</label><input type="number" name="discount" id="discount" value="10" required disabled></div>
          <div><label for="total">Total</label><input type="text" name="total" id="total" value="0" required disabled></div>
          <div><input type="submit" value="Calculate" id="submitCal"></div>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your calculate function, take one event parameter and prevent the default action from occurring:

```
function calculate(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    //other code will work 
}
```

Then use an event in your call:

```
<button onclick="calculate(e)">Calculate</button>
```

And it will work